# Search through JSON (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data, which looks like this:

```
{
  "7070-1002_": {
    "rName": "red",
    "pX": "8061",
    "pY": "2101"
  },
  "7070-1004_": {
    "rName": "green",
    "pX": "7979",
    "pY": "2251"
  },
  "7070-1006_": {
    "rName": "yellow",
    "pX": "7863",
    "pY": "2388"
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to search trough data. For example, I want to get `pX` and `pY` of data with rName `red`(next time it can be green and so on). Could ypu please help me with advice how could I solve it?..

Comment: ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698) On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate trough all the properties with `for ... of` and check if `rName` is red and then do whatever you want with `pX` and `pY` of that element.

```
json = {
    "7070-1002_": {
      "rName": "red",
      "pX": "8061",
      "pY": "2101"
    },
    "7070-1004_": {
      "rName": "green",
      "pX": "7979",
      "pY": "2251"
    },
    "7070-1006_": {
      "rName": "yellow",
      "pX": "7863",
      "pY": "2388"
    }
  }

for(let element in json)
{
    if(json[element].rName === "red")
    {
        console.log(json[element].pX, json[element].pY);
    }
}
```